# replacing the dot with <br /> using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using this example:

> `New Zealand cyclist Jack Bauer didn't know it during the Olympic road race, but there was a scantily-clad Kiwi 'snow angel' above him. http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/olympics/7374497/Near-naked-snow-angel-over-cycle-road-race`

I want to add a `<br />` tag after the full stop but not in HTTP link. Just at the end of the sentence.

Currently I am using :

```
$full_story = $read_story->[0]{story_text}; 
$full_story =~ s/(\D)\.(\D)/<br \/><br \/>/i;
```

Using this code it adds the `<br />` but the `m` from `him` is being removed.

Final Result:

```
New Zealand cyclist Jack Bauer didn't know it during the Olympic road race, but there was a scantily-clad Kiwi 'snow angel' above him.

http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/olympics/7374497/Near-naked-snow-angel-over-cycle-road-race
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a search and replace   's///'

given the string:

```
my $string = 'The quick brown fox. Jumps over the lazy dog.';
```

you could do:

```
$string =~ s/\./<br \/>/g
```

the 's' means you're doing a search and replace.

Between the first two '/ /' is the one you're searching for. In this case it's a dot (.) but you have to escape it with \ since dot in regex is a wild card.

Between the next '/ /' is the text you're trying to replace. In this case it's `<br />`. again you have to escape '/' in here since it's a special character.

Lastly, the 'g' flag at the end means your searching and replacing in the whole string.
So in my example the output would be:

```
print $string;
# The quick brown fox<br /> Jumps over the lazy dog<br />
```

Since you don't want to replace the dots in the string, you could simple separate them in different variables so that it will be easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$full_story =~ s/(.*?)\.(.*?)/$1<br \/><br \/>$2/i;
```

Comment: Hi, how to repeat the search. It just replaces in the first sentence only, sorry I am very bad in regex.

Comment: Add the "g" modifier, e.g. ``.../ig``.

Comment: Thanks, but it there a way to eacape it from the http tag because it break the http link: http://www.

stuff.

co.

nz/sport/olympics/7374497/Near-naked-snow-angel-over-cycle-road-race

Comment: You need a URL-matching regex, of which there are plenty on Stack Overflow. Let's call it ``<url-matching-regex>`` for now. Then, the regex you want is probably something like ``s#\.\s*(?=<url-matching-regex>)#.<br />#g``.

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` to establish the length of the first part of the string up to any `http` link. Then use `substr` as an lvalue to replace all full-stops in just that part.

This code shows the idea. I have added a couple of extra full-stops for testing purposes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q{New Zealand cyclist Jack Bauer. didn't know it during the Olympic. road race, but there was a scantily-clad Kiwi 'snow angel' above him.http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/olympics/7374497/Near-naked-snow-angel-over-cycle-road-race};

my $index = index lc $str, 'http';
$index = length $str if $index < 0;
substr($str, 0, $index) =~ s|\.|.<br/>\n<br/>\n|g;

print $str;
```

**output**

```
New Zealand cyclist Jack Bauer.<br/>
<br/>
 didn't know it during the Olympic.<br/>
<br/>
 road race, but there was a scantily-clad Kiwi 'snow angel' above him.<br/>
<br/>
http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/olympics/7374497/Near-naked-snow-angel-over-cycle-road-race
```